# Drag and Drop (Text)View on ListView item

Tags: java, android, android-listview, drag-and-drop

The problem:
I have a TextView which I can drag. I have a ListView next to it. I want to drag the TextView onto the ListView row. Than color the row if the textview matches the row.

How can I get the ListView item after a drop event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way!

In my custom adapter I have to set the onDragListener on the recycled view and return true <- this is what I haven't done.